# Serilog mssqlserver sink for .NET Core 3.1

Tags: serilog-aspnetcore, serilog-sinks-mssqlserver

My C# Web API project running on .NET Core 3.1 on my dev box is using `Serilog.aspnetcore` v3.4 and writes to SQL Server using `Serilog.sinks.mssqlserver` v5.8.0.

All very good for the development environment, but I notice the prod environment I will deploy to only has .NET Core 3.1 and .NET framework 4.6.2 installed.

A few of the dependencies for `Serilog.sink.mssqlserver` are running on .NET 5.0 (e.g. `Serilog.Sinks.PeriodBatching` depends on `System.Reflection` v4.3 which replies on .NETCore.Platforms 5.0.0).

Will I run into trouble when I deploy my project (file-based deployment) to PROD?

Thanks in advance